# Why am I getting "UnboundLocalError" in this code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, linked-list

I am getting UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev' referenced before assignment on the given code below

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value,next=None):
        self.value=value
        self.next=next

class MyList:
    def __init__(self,a):
        self.head=None
        tail=None
        for i in a:
            n=Node(i,None)
            if self.head is None:
                self.head=n
                tail=n
            else:
                tail.next=n
                tail=n
    
    def showList(self):
        n=self.head
        if n==None:
            print("Empty list")
        while n!=None:
            print(n.value)
            n=n.next

    def isEmpty(self):
        n=self.head
        if n is None:
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")

    def clear(self):
        while(self.head!=None):
            temp=self.head
            self.head=self.head.next
            temp=None
    
    
    
    def insert(self, newElement):
        node = self.head
        while node:
            if node.value == newElement:
                print("Value already exists")
                return False  
            prev = node  
            node = node.next
    
        if prev:
            prev.next = Node(newElement)
        else:  
            self.head = Node(newElement)
        return True



list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
linklist = MyList(list1)
linklist.showList()
linklist.isEmpty()
linklist.clear()
linklist.showList()
linklist.insert(6)  
linklist.showList()
```

If I remove the clear(self) function the code is working perfectly but when it is not removed an error is showing in the insert(self,newElement) function. It is showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\acer\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 65, in <module>
    linklist.insert(6)
  File "c:\Users\acer\Desktop\Untitled-1.py", line 51, in insert
    if prev:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'prev' referenced before assignment
PS C:\Users\acer>
```

Comment: Your *while* loop is never entered, indicating that the *head* member is uninitialized.

Answer (score 1):

In your `insert` method, you need to initialize `prev` to `None` before entering the loop.  Otherwise, if the loop exits before the first iteration (i.e., if `self.head` is `None`), then `prev` will be undefined, which is what Python is telling you.  Just add the initialization like so:

```
    def insert(self, newElement):]
        prev = None
        node = self.head
        while node:
            ...
```

Comment: If I do this, then the problem is I am not getting my desired output. In insert method the code above inserts a new element and check if the element already exists in the list. If it exits then it doesn't insert the value and if it doen't exist then it adds the value to the list. If I set prev= None at the beginning and call linklist.insert(6) it is giving ouput 6. Where the output should be 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: @Jhonny Initializing `prev` to `None` before entering the loop will have no effect on the behavior of the method when called on a non-empty list, since `prev` will be updated inside the loop.  The only case it affects is the case where `self.head` is `None`, in which case it will function correctly rather than producing a runtime error.  There is no case that currently works that won't continue to work with this change.

Comment: @Jhonny Were you able to understand my explanation?  Try my solution.  It will not do what you claimed it would when you said it wouldn't work.  It *will* fix your problem.  Try it.

Comment: Yes I have understand the mistake. The problem was self.head= None

Answer (score 0):

In your `insert()` method if you do not enter the `while` loop then the `prev` variable will not be initialised.

What you need to do is initialise it to something at the start of your `insert()` method or ensure that you are always entering the `while` loop.

Comment: But doing this I am not getting the desired result from the insert method